# 'XML Element[population], child of element[world] not defined in SDF'?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I followed the tutorial on populations of models and encountered such error 'XML Element[population], child of element[world] not defined in SDF'.
I'm new to Gazebo.Could anyone tells what went wrong, thanks!
[Population of models](http://www.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=model_population&cat=build_world)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7291/%27xml-element%5Bpopulation%5D,-child-of-element%5Bworld%5D-not-defined-in-sdf%27???/) by [BenWashburn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1004/benwashburn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In order to use the populations feature, you need to build sdformat (sdf_2.0 branch) and gazebo (default branch) from source, since we haven't yet released the code that uses those features.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BenWashburn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1004/benwashburn/) on 2014-10-23**:
Thanks a lot. It's quite helpful.

**Comment by [jforce](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1077/jforce/) on 2015-01-13**:
I tried this with SDF 2 and Gazebo 4.1.  The can tutorial worked great, but when I tried to insert a  model with a plugin into the same world with the cans, the client and server both exit.  I would include code but I was able to reproduce it with the model plugin model_push.cc tutorial code.